# Go routine blocks another go routine

Tags: go, concurrency

I have two go rutines that are working with the same function, but with different params. When I run the program it runs well, but only 1 rutine was working, and the other was dead/sleeping for some reason.
I used mutex for block the read/write. I used two mutex:

- mutexSearch: To use in busquedaBid function
- mutexCompare: To use in checkEqualityValues function

When one rutine take the lock and reach the unlock it never releases the code block causing the other routine to never work.

This is what I tried:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "math/rand"
    "sort"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var mutexCompare sync.Mutex

type Cola struct {
    tomarLista         int
    contadorSoluciones int
    cola               [][]int
}

func main() {
    in := time.Now()
    puzzleInicial := []int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0}
    grafo := make(map[int][]int)
    grafo[0] = []int{1, 3}
    grafo[1] = []int{0, 2, 4}
    grafo[2] = []int{1, 5}
    grafo[3] = []int{0, 4, 6}
    grafo[4] = []int{1, 3, 5, 7}
    grafo[5] = []int{2, 4, 8}
    grafo[6] = []int{3, 7}
    grafo[7] = []int{4, 6, 8}
    grafo[8] = []int{5, 7}
    puzzleFinal := []int{1, 3, 6, 5, 2, 0, 4, 7, 8}
    colaInicial := [][]int{}
    colaFinal := [][]int{}
    colaInicial = append(colaInicial, puzzleInicial)
    colaFinal = append(colaFinal, puzzleFinal)
    tomarListaInicial := 0
    contadorSolucionesInicial := 0
    mutexSearch := &sync.Mutex{}
    done := make(chan bool)
    colaI := Cola{tomarListaInicial, contadorSolucionesInicial, colaInicial}
    colaF := Cola{tomarListaInicial, contadorSolucionesInicial, colaFinal}
    go busquedaBid(&colaI, &colaF, grafo, mutexSearch, done)
    go busquedaBid(&colaF, &colaI, grafo, mutexSearch, done)
    <-done
    f := time.Since(in)
    fmt.Println(f)
}

func busquedaBid(colaActual *Cola, colaCheck *Cola, grafo map[int][]int, mut *sync.Mutex,
    done chan bool) {
    for {
        mut.Lock()
        nodo := getIndex(colaActual.cola[colaActual.tomarLista])
        for _, neighbour := range grafo[nodo] {
            sliceAux := append([]int(nil), colaActual.cola[colaActual.tomarLista]...)
            valorAux := sliceAux[neighbour]
            indCero := getIndex(sliceAux)
            sliceAux[neighbour] = 0
            sliceAux[indCero] = valorAux
            if !checkRepetitionsSlices(colaActual.cola, sliceAux) {
                colaActual.cola = append(colaActual.cola, sliceAux)
            }
        }
        colaActual.tomarLista += 1
        mut.Unlock()
        if checkEqualityValues(colaActual.cola, colaCheck.cola, done) {
            break
        }
    }
}

func checkEqualityValues(cola_inicial [][]int, cola_final [][]int, done chan bool) bool {
    mutexCompare.Lock()
    for _, item1 := range cola_inicial {
        for _, item2 := range cola_final {
            if checkRepetitionsSliceSlice(item1, item2) {
                fmt.Println(len(cola_inicial), len(cola_final))
                close(done)
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    mutexCompare.Unlock()
    return false
}
```

For example this is an output:
115 1

That output says to me that only one rutine was worked, because the other one didn't put any slice in the queue (the queue it's a slice of slices)

Sorry if a maked a bigmistake, I'm new and I'm learning go

Comment: checkEqualityValues returns without unlocking mutexCompare after printing. Even if you fix this, main returns right after, and that terminates the program without waiting for the second goroutine.

Comment: For concurrency problems like this, the standard pattern in Go is to make liberal use of channels rather than mutexes: https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#channels

Answer (score 1):

I think I solve the problem. I made a for loop that contains 3 goroutines:

- Two for the function "busquedaBid" (this function make a type of bidirectional search)
- One for "checkEqualityValues" (this function determines if two slices are equals)

Adittionally I used `sync.WaitGroup` and I puted the `wg.Done()` sentence in functions, that solve the block problem between routines.

(I don't know if this solution is in a go way)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "math/rand"
    "sort"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var mutexCompare sync.Mutex
var flag bool = false


type Cola struct {
    tomarLista         int
    contadorSoluciones int
    cola               [][]int
}

func main() {
    in := time.Now()
    puzzleInicial := []int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0}
    grafo := make(map[int][]int)
    grafo[0] = []int{1, 3}
    grafo[1] = []int{0, 2, 4}
    grafo[2] = []int{1, 5}
    grafo[3] = []int{0, 4, 6}
    grafo[4] = []int{1, 3, 5, 7}
    grafo[5] = []int{2, 4, 8}
    grafo[6] = []int{3, 7}
    grafo[7] = []int{4, 6, 8}
    grafo[8] = []int{5, 7}
    puzzleFinal := []int{1, 3, 6, 5, 2, 0, 4, 7, 8}
    colaInicial := [][]int{}
    colaFinal := [][]int{}
    colaInicial = append(colaInicial, puzzleInicial)
    colaFinal = append(colaFinal, puzzleFinal)
    mutexSearch := &sync.Mutex{}
    colaI := Cola{0, 0, colaInicial}
    colaF := Cola{0, 0, colaFinal}
    mutexSearch := &sync.Mutex{}
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for {
        if flag {
            return
        }
        wg.Add(3)
        go busquedaBid(&colaF, &colaI, grafo, mutexSearch, wg)
        go busquedaBid(&colaI, &colaF, grafo, mutexSearch, wg)
        go checkEqualityValues(colaI.cola, colaF.cola, wg)
        wg.Wait()
    }
}

func busquedaBid(colaActual *Cola, colaCheck *Cola, grafo map[int][]int, mut *sync.Mutex, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    mut.Lock()
    nodo := getIndex(colaActual.cola[colaActual.tomarLista])
    for _, neighbour := range grafo[nodo] {
        sliceAux := append([]int(nil), colaActual.cola[colaActual.tomarLista]...)
        sliceAux[getIndex(sliceAux)] = sliceAux[neighbour]
        sliceAux[neighbour] = 0
        if checkRepetitionsMapSlice(colaActual.cola, sliceAux) == false {
            colaActual.cola = append(colaActual.cola, sliceAux)
        }
    }
    colaActual.tomarLista += 1
    mut.Unlock()
    wg.Done()
}

func checkEqualityValues(cola_inicial [][]int, cola_final [][]int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    mutexCompare.Lock()
    for _, item1 := range cola_inicial {
        for _, item2 := range cola_final {
            if checkRepetitionsSliceSlice(item1, item2) {
                flag = true
                fmt.Println(runtime.NumGoroutine())
                mutexCompare.Unlock()
                wg.Done()
            }
        }
    }
    mutexCompare.Unlock()
    wg.Done()
}
```